# Best way to lay vinyl in this room

Tags: vinyl-flooring

[image]

My biggest problem is that the bottom of the cabinet are so close to the ground, I may only get 1mm clearance so it's difficult to slide vinyl sheet in.  The cabinet in picture 2 can easily be removed and perhaps I can mark the cabinet legs out and cut holes however the cabinet in picture 3, I cannot even pull it out because it is hitting the floor so would probably struggle to push vinyl under it and removing it seems more work than its worth.

I know, the best way would be to remove all remaining cabinets and if need be raise the tops surfaces and sink at the end, but that sounds like a lot of work.

So am wondering how to get vinyl in one piece of possible in the whole kitchen.

I guess this cannot be done unless every time to a side shelf(the standing parts that support table tops and cabinet shelves) I have to cut the shape out as though I was sliding the sheet forward and then add the shape in at the end and silicone any gaps?

Instead of wrestling the sheet in and cutting as I go, if I just measured the whole kitchen and cut parts out such as where the shelves are standing then tried to slot it in place, would that work?

Anyway please advice how might it be best to get a vinyl sheet in this hole kitchen bearing in mind I probably won't want to take all cabinets apart more than what I've done and it seems impossible to slide the sheet under the legs as there is not enough clearance.

[image][image]

Answer (score 2):

Do it properly, remove the worktop, remaing cupboards, then level the floor surface.

Put down the new vinyl in one piece where it will fit to the perimeter properly.

Refit the cupboards and make sure all are level and square. Then re-fitting the worktop will be easy.

I dropped a long worktop by 2” - made all the cuts after removing the top and it went back on with no problem.

You get more issues by bodging one step then having to bodge the next and the next than doing it properly in the first place.

Comment: The cabinets are screwed in at a particular height.  The worktops are also joined into he walls. You will need to re-screw cabinets to a higher height and also cut into tiles and  the side wall to increase work top height.  How is that easy?

Comment: No no no, **You** will need to deal with the cabinets and screws. Why don't you consider removing 3mm or the tile thickness from the bottom of the cabinets then all the upper fixings are still the same?

Comment: the cabinets have no tiles underneath them, just concrete.  i dont think i can educe the concrete.

Comment: So your cabinets are made of concrete? Sorry this is just too challenging.

Comment: oh u meant saw the bottom of the cabinets and move the screws up?  that would work, still more work. As i do this i'm really ill, its tough hence wanted the quick fix.

Comment: If all of the cabinet supporting panels were moved, wouldnt the table top collapse due to lack of support.  if u say do one at a time, before you slide the vinyl in they will all be off the ground so wouldnt it collapse at this point?

Comment: I have find a way to decrease the the length without cutting.  If you look closely at the bottom of the panels you can see circle legs, these can be modified to reduce the height.  However in picture 1 right in the middle there are two glued panels which will need to be removed.  Mike, were you suggesting to remove the tabletops, then reduce height(now without sawing), then rebuild it? I though you were suggesting to leave the tops and reduce the height but I guess this is not the case?