# Can I join different flooring to cover a height gap?

Tags: vinyl-flooring

3/4 of my kitchen has tiles in it the other 1/4 has no tiles, just the concrete underneath so there is a height difference.

You may wonder why I don't take the tiles out and level everything but its complicated and most importantly I hope to move out of here soon so don't need a great floor.

Anyway I have some spare vinyl lying around may use that for 1/4 of the room and will get new sheet for the other 3/4.

It maybe the case that the sheets need to be joined at an angle due to the height difference.  Can you use the standard way to seam to accomplish this or will it come off or just be an ok job?  As I say doesn't need to be perfect job just functional until I get out in some months.

Also if the flooring is going at angle does that mean it will rip over time, how can I prevent this(without leveling the subfloor as I don't want to if possible)?

Comment: Concrete underneath what? Air is always there but this is unclear.

Comment: It’s complicated, but having a height difference especially at an angle in a room can be a trip or fall hazard. Sure there are step thresholds going from tile to vinyl but it will look like more of a hack in my opinion.

Comment: @SolarMike i meant the concrete subfloor is exposed and the remainder of the room has tiles.

Comment: What does "at an angle" mean? Please revise to describe better what we're talking about.

Comment: got any pictures?

Answer (score 1):

No you can't.   Well you can but you wouldn't be doing anything right.   There isn't a suitable transition piece that would hold up to use for tile to vinyl transition at an angle.   Actually the only way you can do angles is going from carpet to tile or tile to tile and while those work they aren't pretty and could be dangerous.

The easiest way to get with the is to flatten the area by the transition and let the rest of the kitchen run at a gradual angle.   There are a ton of ways you can transition this setup and you will probably just end up with a simple U channel metal strip - where the butt side is against tile and vinyl inserted into U.

The other option is just to tile the who thing and use some kind of border tile to do the transition - again could be a trip hazard and isn't really right.   If you are selling the house soon it seems kind of dumb spending time to do something wrong when others will make you pay for it in the sale price.

Comment: Well, consider the possibility he is renting, then check this question: https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/191638/97780

Answer (score 1):

If you're renting, get the landlord to do it. If he's not interested, remind him that the bills for a "trip" could be expensive.

If it's your property, put a thin underlayment on the concrete to raise the floor height so the final vinyl surface will match up with the current tile surface.