# Will removing supporting cabinets cause table top to fall?

Tags: cabinets

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

This question is not the same though as comments suggested.  This is specifically asking whether they table top will fall in light of how it has been constructed. It is not asking the best way to install a vinyl.  Maybe I want to try an alternative route but have concerns whether the table top will fall. Maybe I also want to avoid pluming work because I do not have tools/am no confident with it.

I am trying to get vinyl underneath some cabinets and I'm hoping I won't have to remove the tabletops.  I have provided pictures of how it seems to be resting.  It may be using the cabinets but were I to remove them the remaining support would be what you see in the pictures.

If I remove the remaining cabinets will the tabletop collapse?

Comment: You are attempting to install flooring under the cabinets.  Does the current flooring go under the cabinets or stop at the toe kick (baseboard of cabinets)?  How long is the counter top?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to lay vinyl in this room](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/191638/best-way-to-lay-vinyl-in-this-room)

Comment: Op has a whole series of closely linked questions about this floor and no accepted answers either.

Comment: @Programmer66 Aboout 230cm across 60cm going down. Current fooring stops at the toe kick but I'd like to cover under cabinets because theres dried adhesive there and its making me sick.  Thanks

Comment: @SolarMike No its different.  From that answer I can see that the cabinets need to be removed, however the tabletop may not need to be.  Trying to avoid plumbing and other table top related work if it is not needed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way to tell if the top would fall without knowing how it was fastened to the wall. You're right that if you add the vinyl and then try to slide the cabinets back in, assuming the top didn't fall, they won't fit. If you tried to force them in, you'd damage the vinyl. You could get a belt sander and remove some material from the bottom of the cabinet. 
Personally, I think your best bet would be to remove the tops and take your time and do the job. Reinstall the cabinets on the vinyl and then install the top, secure and caulk the sides. good luck and stay safe out there.

Comment: Already told the op to do the job properly - hope you have better luck than I did...

Comment: @solar mike was that a dupe question I think I remember another cabinet one but did not look. If so one should be closed.

Comment: May well have to remove the tabletops however trying to avoid plumming and other tabletop work if not needed.  I have added pics of table top support.  Dont know if glue is used anywhere.  Do you still think I need to remove table tops?  Table top is 230cm by 60cm.  Thanks.

Comment: @JamesWilson  You can probably leave the tops in place but I'd have a few 2x4's  supporting it.  You can move the supports around as needed while placing your vinyl and then moving them back afterwards. keep them in place while putting the cabinets back in place. you'll have to shave off some of the cabinets due to the additional height of the floor due to the vinyl.

Comment: Thanks jack this is about as good a work around without moving the tabletop.  I have found that the panels do not need to be trimmed because they have some adjustable circular legs at the bottom.  This being the case you could remove a panel, lay the vinyl past it and add the panel back and repeat for other panels. This would ensure support for the table top.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the last cabinet on the right, the countertop will not fall if you take some precautions.  The countertop on the right end is supported by the sides of the last remaining cabinet.  You would just need to support the counter by:
1. Add temporary support under the counter at the end where the tile is

2. Add temporary support from floor to counter on the left side of the remaining cabinet. It does not have to be flat against the cabinet, but can be a few inches away.
3. If you are not reusing the cabinet, you could dismantle the cabinet and leave the two side panel up like you did in the other pictures.
4. It appears that the countertop does not have a front lip.  With a front lip, you would not be able to slide the cabinet out.
   [image]

   [image]